# Notation to show PSD matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm struggling to understand what this notation for matrix P means:
[image]

My inclination is that this refers to P being a Positive Semi Definite matrix, but I have never seen this S notation before. Can someone clarify?

This comes from Boyd's classic convex optimization.

Comment: The notation is defined in the book. It means the set of symmetric, positive semi definite $n \times n$ matrices.